# Why I am getting different screen session when opened from a bash script

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I am opening a new screen in detached mode from the following one-liner bash script:

```
screen -d -m -S screenName
```

But the terminal prompt of screen displays `bash-3.2$` instead of my regular prompt `atul.vaibhav@Mac$`.

When I execute the same command directly from terminal, I get normal expected prompt. Why am I getting a different prompt when opening a screen from bash script?

I am executing my bash script in this manner:

```
./myScript.sh
```

Comment: Probably not a login shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the synopsis from `man screen` gives:

> ```
> screen [ -options ] [ cmd [ args ] ]
> ```

and you want a login Bash shell, you should probably run:

```
screen -d -m -S screenName -- bash -l
```

That said, while the command ran and `ps` claimed to have created a `bash -l` somewhere, I couldn't see the window.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
bash -l ./myScript.sh
```

or

```
bash -i ./myScript.sh
```

---

From `man bash`:

> `-l`: Make bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell.
>
> `-i`: If the -i option is present, the shell is interactive.